# Fetch keys across all documents in a couchbase bucket

Tags: couchbase

i am trying to access bucket keys for couchbase 6.0 cluster and wondering if there is any way to capture all keys in a bucket?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show what you've tried and what problem you had?

Answer (score 3):

By "bucket key" I assume you mean "document key".

A N1QL query can do this: `SELECT META().id FROM yourbucket` but depending on how much data you have, that query could take a lot of time to execute. This query will require a primary index (`CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON yourbucket`) which is usually not a good idea to have in production.

Why do you need to get every key?

Comment: You need to have Primary Index. You can also do in batches.  SELECT META().id FROM bucket WHERE META().id > "some key" LIMIT 1000; Next time change "some key" last value from your previous results.